# Ruby EventMachine - how to return values from EM::Deferrable to main EM loop?

Tags: ruby, callback, eventmachine

I'm playing with EventMachine for some days now which has a steep learn curve IMHO ;-) I try to return a hash by triggering HttpHeaderCrawler.query() which I need within the callback. But what I get in this case is not the hash {'http_status' => xxx, 'http_version' => xxx} but an EventMachine::HttpClient Object itself.

I wanna keep the EM.run block clean and wanna do all logic within own classes / modules so how to return such a value into the main loop to access it by the callback? Many thanks in advance ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http-request'

class HttpHeaderCrawler
  include EM::Deferrable

  def query(uri)
    http = EM::HttpRequest.new(uri).get
    http.callback do
      http_header = {
        "http_status" => http.response_header.http_status,
        "http_version" => http.response_header.http_version
      }
      puts "Returns to EM main loop: #{http_header}"
      succeed(http_header)
    end
  end
end

EM.run do
  domains = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.facebook.com', 'http://www.twitter.com']
  domains.each do |domain|
    hdr = HttpHeaderCrawler.new.query(domain)
    hdr.callback do |header|
      puts "Received from HttpHeaderCrawler: #{header}"
    end
  end
end
```

This snippet produces the following output:

```
Returns to EM main loop: {"http_status"=>302, "http_version"=>"1.1"}
Received from HttpHeaderCrawler: #<EventMachine::HttpClient:0x00000100d57388>
Returns to EM main loop: {"http_status"=>301, "http_version"=>"1.1"}
Received from HttpHeaderCrawler: #<EventMachine::HttpClient:0x00000100d551a0>
Returns to EM main loop: {"http_status"=>200, "http_version"=>"1.1"}
Received from HttpHeaderCrawler: #<EventMachine::HttpClient:0x00000100d56280>
```

Comment: I like [this tutorial by Martyn Loughran](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/10/01/an-introduction-to-eventmachine-and-how-to-avoid-callback-spaghetti/) for suggesting ways to avoid "spaghetti callback code".

Comment: Yepp, I know this tutorial. Good approach for starting with EM. But what I don't undestand there: Martyn returns a value in his em-http-request sample the same way I do in the snippet above. Don't see whats going wrong in my case

Comment: This is strange. Replacing query(uri) by initialize(uri) in HttpHeaderCrawler and hdr = HttpHeaderCrawler.new.query(domain)
 by hdr = HttpHeaderCrawler.new(domain) solves all. But why?

Comment: The only difference I spotted is his code uses `self.succeed()` and `self.fail()`, where yours leaves off the `self.`. Is that enough to create the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is `#query` returns `http.callback`, which returns the http object itself,  whereas it should return `self`, i.e. the HttpHeaderCrawler. See if this works.

```
def query(uri)
  http = EM::HttpRequest.new(uri).get
  http.callback do
    http_header = {
      "http_status" => http.response_header.http_status,
      "http_version" => http.response_header.http_version
    }
    puts "Returns to EM main loop: #{http_header}"
    succeed(http_header)
  end
  self
end
```

Comment: Hey Eric. Cool, that's exactely the reason for my trouble. All works fine nowö THANKS :)